# Decoding 4 byte latitude/4 byet longitude of Concox TR06 GPS tracker

Tags: c#, gps

We have a Concox TG06 GPS tracker. I am receiving data from it via TCP, but I am struggling to decode the latitude and longitude coordinates (in C#). According to the protocol manual, the message from the tracker (terminal) to the server looks like this:

[image: Concox TR06 position protocol]

As you can see, the latitude and longitude coordinates are 4 bytes each. Further down, the manual explains how these coordinates are formatted:

***5.2.1.6 Latitude***
Four bytes are consumes, defining the latitude value of location data. The range of the value is 0 - 162000000, indicating a range of 0°-90°. The conversion method thereof is as follow:
Converting the value of latitude and longitude output by GPS module into a decimal based on minute; multiplying the converted decimal by 30000; and converting the multiplied result into hexadecimal. Example: 22º32.7658’=(22X60+32.7658)X30000=40582974, then converted into a hexadecimal number 40582974(Decimal)= 26B3F3E(Hexadecimal) at last the value is 0x02 0x6B 0x3F 0x3E

I am REALLY struggling to work this out backwards - i.e. getting from the four bytes (0x02 0x6B 0x3F 0x3E) to the latitude coordinate (not necessarily in degrees and minutes, as I use decimal degrees in my code). Basically I am trying to create a function whose shell looks like this:

```
private double DecodeLat(byte[] latBytes)
{
    double latitude;
    // implementation
    return latitude;
{
```

(And obviously same for longitude). I would greatly appreciate any help at all!

Thank you

Comment: Can we see implementation ?

Comment: I am using this device to create server and store data. I am getting **<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 58 73 50 70 78 75 68 00 35 c6 d3 0d 0a>** as initial data. I am not able to decode it. can you please share some links or share dummy sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode it as follows:

```
public static decimal DecodeLatitude(byte[] bytes)
{
    decimal minutes = (bytes[0] << 24) + (bytes[1] << 16) + (bytes[2] << 8) + bytes[3];
    minutes /= 30000;

    return minutes;
}
```

See an example [here](http://ideone.com/TdGv65).

Comment: Hi Phylogenesis. Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I seem to be getting strange values, but we are in South Africa, and therefore southern hemisphere, and I'm wondering how the negative is handled.... Could it be that the most significant bit denotes the hemisphere?

Comment: I don't know why, but I added another line to your code:

minutes /= 60;

because it just looked like it needed it :) and it's looking better... I'll let you know shortly if it's correct...

Comment: @user1900799 That's because the function returns the number of minutes, and there are 60 minutes in a degree.

Answer (score 1):

The longitude is 4 bytes
because I can not see implementation I assume
you try to read the double with

```
BitConverter.ToDouble(Buffer, index);
```

a double = 8 bytes

if this is not the case Let me know in the comment, please

Answer (score 0):

For concox protocol the conversion of binary data is pretty straightforward - you just scan 4 binary bytes into number (little endian - e.g. just simple conversion to 32-bit unsigned integer) and then divide this number by 1800000.0. The result is in [decimal degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees). Southern and Western hemispheres are defined by the sign, and sign is located in special bit of byte followed by the coordinates.

If you will have troubles with further data parsing from the device take a look at specialized cloud services that provide full protocol parsing and output completed parsed JSON message, like [this](https://flespi.com/blog/how-to-access-messages-in-flespi-http-mqtt-and-more).

Disclaimer: I'm related to flespi parsing backend and my opinion can be influenced by this product.

Answer (score 0):

Take for instance converting the Hex Latitude `0x027AC7EB` to degrees.

You can do conversion in 4 steps:

1. Convert the Hex Lat value to Decimal:
   `0x027AC7EB` => `41601003`
2. Divide the value you get by `30000`:
   41601003 / 30000 => `1,386.7001`
3. Divide by `60` to convert the value to degrees:
   1,386.7001 / 60 => `23.11166833333333 degrees`
4. Prefix the `minus` or `plus` depending on the hemisphere.

   How it works?

   For Latitude:  - North prefix `+`
   - South prefix `-`

   For Longitude: - East  prefix `+`
   - West  prefix `-`

   You can extract these positioning values from the `Course and Status` Bytes

eg. if decoding the course and status byte evaluates to a `South` `Latitude`, the final Latitude value would be `-23.11166833333333 degrees`

Same process applies for decoding the `Longitude`.